# assigning unsigned char* to string C++

Tags: c++

This is my sample code. Please let me know why it crashes over here.

```
string MyFunction::GetString(unsigned char* inStrReference)
{
    unsigned char* bufPtr = inStrReference; 

    string newstring = (char*)bufPtr;

    return newstring;
}
```

Comment: if you do a function like that it is good practice to check the argument before starting to work with it.

Answer (score 13):

First of all the code is identical to the much less verbose:

```
string MyFunction::GetString(unsigned char* inStrReference) {
   return inStrReference;
}
```

In fact, as it is the whole function is completely unnecessary. If `var = GetString(s);` is valid then `var = s;` is guaranteed to be valid as well and to produce the same identical result.

As for the crash, it's probably because `inStrReference` doesn't point to a valid memory area that contains a zero terminated string. In other words, we need more details on how this function is called to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: At least on my system there is no constructor which takes a char pointer with a different char type than the underlying type. `string s = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(0);` gives the error `error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char*’ to ‘const char*’`.